# Architecture for making Network Calls and parsing the JSON response

Tags: android, json, okhttp, android-mvp

I am working on a new Android Application and I would like to organise all the components - Network Call class, JSON parsing class etc. properly. I am using Okhttp for network calls; After a lot of research I was able to structure my code like this:

My NetworkUtil Class:

```
public class NetworkUtil {

public static void getData(String url, final OkHttpListener listener){
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    // GET request
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            listener.onFailure(request, e);
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            listener.onResponse(response);
        }
    });
}
```

My network callback interface:

```
public interface OkHttpListener {
void onFailure(Request request, IOException e);
void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException;
}
```

And this is my Activity class:

```
OkHttpListener listener = new OkHttpListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            String responseBody = response.body().string();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, responseBody);
        }
    };
    String url = "http://myserver/api/getvalues";
    OkHttpUtils.getData(url, listener);
    String url1 = "http://myserver/api/getvalues/123";
    OkHttpUtils.getData(url1, listener);
}
```

Here are the issues that I am facing:

1. I want to make multiple network calls from an Activity/Fragment based on different events, how do I design the Activity class in such a way that I am able to make multiple requests. I would also like to keep a separate class (an Application class maybe) for all the common methods that will be used in the Activities. I want to make my architecture cohesive.
2. I would like parse the JSON response in a separate class and pass the results to my Activity class. How do I **parse the JSON response in a separate class and pass the results to my Activity/Fragment class from the onSuccess() method in my NetworkUtil class**
3. I would like to use no libraries or very less libraries (at least for the JSON parsing part) throughout this project, at this moment I will be sticking with only okhttp.

It will be of great help if someone could refer me to a git repository or a sample project to have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code can't be tested and breaks SOLID principles, your activity will soon became too huge to easily maintain. Try to avoid using Utils classes in case like that. Use IoC. So I recommend you to take a look at MVP/MVVM or any other presentation pattern.

1. You should create separate function for each API call.
2. Working with JSON should be definitely moved out from your activity. As you using OkHttp, I recommend you to use Retrofit over it. It's higher level which makes your API calls easies and you can use Gson/Jackson/Moshi or any other library as built-in adapter, so you won't care about serialising/marshalling Json string into Java objects, Retrofit adapters will take care of it.

Search for some articles about MVP pattern and take a look at [this](https://github.com/antoniolg/androidmvp) repository. Good luck.

Comment: I checked the repository you mentioned and a few more repositories on MVP/MVVM but they all use retrofit, GSON or some libraries for JSON parsing. I want to keep my library count as less as possible. Can't the response that I got in onResponse under networkUtil class be passed to the Activity class under on onResponse through a thread or a handler?

Comment: @localhost you can use MVP using your libraries as well. It's all about delegating tasks to classes and chaining them. Your OkHttp's method enqueue is async. So what's the point of your listener?

Comment: the listener interface helps me reuse the code, in my case the networkUtil class - with URI to multiple APIs that I want to call

Comment: @localhost well, I gave you recommendations/improvements, now it's up to you. But static utils classes is pure evil :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). You can init it with `GsonConverterFactory`to deal with JSON and parse it by using pojoclass [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Here is an sample code:

```
 String BASE_URL = "https://YOUR API";
            Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
            apiService = builder.build().create(ApiService.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I understand your concerns in using a lot of o libraries I would definitely recommend `Retrofit`, it is the industry standard for a good reason (you can quickly google search why).

For parsing, you should use `Moshi` since you are already using `Okhttp`.

Another suggestion is to move your code to a more appropriate and scalable pattern such as MVP or MVVM. One thing you **must** take into account:

Fragments and/or Activities are not yours, they're Android owned objects, meaning they can be destroyed at any second.

Doing asynchronous work on these unstable objects is the recipe or bad code and memory leaks. Hence a good software pattern is super important in this environment.

I would recommend MVP if you are starting out, I've written a blog post about this where you can take your first steps:

[image: Avenging]
[Android MVP without RxJava or Dagger](https://android.jlelse.eu/avenging-android-mvp-23461aebe9b5)